# Change Windows scroll bar dragging behavior on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-interface

Though it is (as things often are) more complicated than this, assume for the purposes of this question that I am a new Windows user, coming from the Mac. I am trying to get certain Windows behaviors to act like they do on the Mac, because that is what I'm used to and prefer. Don't judge me. :)

One thing that has consistently bothered me is the scrollbar dragging behavior. When the mouse pointer strays a certain (short) distance from the scrollbar, the thumb snaps back to its original, pre-drag position. I want to change it so that this does not happen; so that, regardless of the pointer's horizontal position on the screen, the thumb continues to track it.

I have read allusions that this is possible, but not how, and Google is failing me. Any tips?

Comment: I have only used Windows in my life, but I still find this "feature" is so very annoying.